# Помогите достать все совпадения из регулярного выражения

Tags: grep, awk

Есть проект, у него используется i18 (библиотека для ключей перевода).

Функция перевода выглядит так:

```
t('NavMenu.toBeClient')
t('NavMenu.text')
```

Мне нужно в один текстовый документ вывести ключи:

```
NavMenu.toBeClient
NavMenu.text
```

А в другой так:

```
"NavMenu.toBeClient"
"NavMenu.text",
```

Регулярка будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
t\('.+'\)
```

Как сделать форматирование средствами grep, awk, cut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F't\\(\x27' '{print $2}' |awk -F'\x27\\)' '{print $1}'
```

если вывод в кавычках то:

```
awk -F't\\(\x27' '{print $2}' |awk -F'\x27\\)' '{print "\""$1"\""}'
```

Comment: А как его применить ко всему проекту? На подобии `grep -E "t\('.+'\)" -r './'`?

Comment: @lasna, попробуйте так: `grep -oh -E "t\('.+'\)" -r './' | awk -F't\\(\x27' '{print $2}' |awk -F'\x27\\)' '{print $1}'`